# Why the address of the variables changes based on how I run the program?

Tags: c, variables, memory-address

I don't understand why the address of the variables changes based on how I run the program. I have this simple code in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[100];
    gets(buffer);
    printf("buf: %p\n", (void*)&buffer);
    printf(buffer);
    return 0;   
}
```

before compiling I used this command to disable the randomization:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

but this is what happens:
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6bmx.png)

in the first execution the address of buffer is bffff084 in the second is bffff024

Comment: *Never* use `gets` (obsolete today). Use at least `fgets` and `getline` if possible

Comment: `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` matters at runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Each time program starts, random number is added to stack address so it would be harder to predict absolute addresses of buffers and write injectable shell code.

Since your program is vulnerable to *buffer overflow* (due to usage of `gets` and statically allocated buffer), it does its work.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say that i use before this command: echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space